# Marman vs collet seperation mechanism

Tags: rockets, stage-separation

The [Marman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marman_clamp) and the [Collet](https://www.quora.com/How-are-rocket-stages-separated-from-each-other) mechanisms are used for stage separation in rockets and launch vehicles.

Which of these is most efficient, cost wise, weight wise and ease of usability wise?

Which of the above is better match for semi-cryo engines?

Comment: different questions, but related: [What types of decoupling mechanisms to separate spacecraft are used in spaceflight?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21429/12102) and of course also [Why GSLV uses different stage seperation mechanism for their different varients](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30746/12102)