# Why GSLV uses different stage seperation mechanism for their different varients

Tags: rockets, stage-separation, gslv

Why [GSLV mk II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geosynchronous_Satellite_Launch_Vehicle#GSLV_Mk_II) is using [Marman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marman_clamp) mechanism for stage separation but [GSLV mk III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geosynchronous_Satellite_Launch_Vehicle_Mark_III) is using [Collet](https://www.quora.com/How-are-rocket-stages-separated-from-each-other) mechanism for stage separation?

Comment: different questions, but related: [What types of decoupling mechanisms to separate spacecraft are used in spaceflight?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21429/12102) and of course also [Marman vs collet seperation mechanism](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30745/12102)

Comment: @uhoh, the second question is also asked by me. And I am still looking for a good answer.

Comment: Linking to related questions causes them to appear in the "Linked" list (on the right side of screen at least when viewed with large format). This way more people may see it and potentially leave an answer. In the future, people reading one of the questions and possibly its answer may see "Linked" and then view the related material. Good for knowledge base as well as for your up votes. Helpful linking adds value to the site.

Comment: Oh! didn't know this till know.